# How to reorder a data frame based on the contents of itself in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
The dataframe

        Value   Time Point  Sample Number
    0   6.9     T000        1
    1   3.45    T000        2
    2   0.159   T000        3
    3   2.933   T024        4
    4   2.9     T024        5
    5   1.88    T024        6
```

I want to reorder it like this:

```
The new dataframe

    Sample Number   1    2      3       4       5      6
             T000  6.9  3.45  0.159    NaN     NaN    NaN
             T024  NaN  NaN    NaN    2.933    2.9    1.88
```

The columns of  new dataframe created from Sample Number and
indexes created from  Time Point

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["6.9", "T000","1"],
        ["3.45", "T000","2"],
        ["0.159", "T000","3"],
        ["2.933", "T024","4"],
        ["2.9", "T024","5"],
        ["1.88", "T024","6"]] 
    
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
df_data.columns = ["Value", "Time Point", "Sample Number"]
    
df_data_new = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_data["Sample Number"], index = df_data["Time Point"].unique())
```

Not sure how to fill in the data value of df_data to new dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

use `set_index` & `unstack`

```
out = df_data.set_index(['Time Point', 'Sample Number'])['Value'].unstack().rename_axis(None)
```

out:

```
Sample Number    1     2      3      4    5     6                                      
T000           6.9  3.45  0.159    NaN  NaN   NaN
T024           NaN   NaN    NaN  2.933  2.9  1.88
```

or use `pivot`

```
out = df_data.pivot(index='Time Point', columns='Sample Number', values='Value').rename_axis(None)
```

same result

Answer (score 3):

Use df.pivot,

```
df_data.pivot(index='Time Point', columns='Sample Number', values='Value')
```

Output:

```
Sample Number    1     2      3      4    5     6
Time Point                                       
T000           6.9  3.45  0.159    NaN  NaN   NaN
T024           NaN   NaN    NaN  2.933  2.9  1.88
```